# Как обзванивать клиента на наличие его online

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Как обзванивать клиента на наличие его `online` в `node.js + socket.io`, как работает эта связка? Мну нужно время от времени заносить в базу id тех кто онлайн. как это отслеживать?

Answer (score 3):

1. создаем в глобальной области видимости скрипта node.js переменную-объект:

   ```
   var online = {};
   ```
2. При установлении сокетного соединения берем его id из свойства connection и делаем ссылку на этот connection:

   ```
   online[id] = connection;
   ```
3. Манипулируем объектом online как того желаем, например, можно перебором свойств объекта узнать, сколько сейчас народу онлайн и т.д.
4. При завершении соединения делаем так:

   ```
   delete online[id];
   ```

Comment: Вы немного не так меня поняли. Все это понятно. Мне нужно каждый раз обновлять временную метку активности пользователя? Поэтому переменная объект создается один раз и один раз создается соединение. И само собой ясное дело, когда клиент уходит, вызывается метод disconnect, который удаляет идентификатор сокета. Но мне нужно это все связать с базой данных вот по такому принципу: http://www.lukemelia.com/blog/archives/2010/01/17/redis-in-practice-whos-online/

Comment: Точно такой же вопрос задавался тут кем-то:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9610286/what-is-the-best-way-to-keep-track-of-which-users-are-online-in-nodejs
там есть один ответ. буду копать. но так же буду рад русскоязычной аудитории

Comment: Интересен программное решение. проштудировал socket.io но кроме настроек heartbeats ничего не нашел, может какой-то call back есть?

Comment: не вижу проблемы - для работы с какой угодно базой в моем ответе преусмотрен пункт 3 ;)  
что-то типа такого:  
    clientRedis.hset("online","user:"+id,"enterTime:"+(new Date()));  
ну и при дисконнекте удалить соответствующий ключ хэша.

Answer (score 1):

Пришла в голову такая идея: Когда пользователь законнектился к серверу через socket.io, заносить его id в хранилище Redis с меткой времени входа.
При дисконнекте соответственно удалять из редиса или добавлять еще одну запись - время выхода. Затем nodо'м опрашивать редис каждые 2 минуты и смотреть кто онлайн и отсылать клиенту. С другой стороны зачем эти заморочки - если можно удалить id из объекта users_online и отослать клиенту - что юзер id вышел. что есть в стандартном случае

Comment: Другой момент. У каждого пользователя есть свой список контактов для переписки. При дисконнекте юзера из списка контактов - как отослать событие(уведомление) только тем, у кого он есть в контактах? Т-е чтобы не делать broadcast?

Comment: У каждого пользователя на сайте есть свой список контактов для переписки. 
Допустим у меня в контактах есть пользователь id = 100.
Когда она выходит из чата, вызывается событие node.js disconnected и отсылает всем клиентам о том, что пользователь id = 100 вышел из чата.

Comment: Но я не хочу чтобы всем отсылалось это сообщение, а хочу только тем, у кого этот контакт есть в списке контактов.
Как вариант - при дисконнекте конкретного пользователя - делать запрос в базу redis и вытягивать от туда id тех, у кого этот контакт в списке друзей. брать их id и по ним отсылать уведомление. Но будет ли это правильно и производительно?